# Is there a way to retain the SNAPSHOT suffix on build artifacts using Maven Release Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, maven-release-plugin

I am using the mvn-release-plugin in batch mode to release the artifacts to both production and lower environments. I would like the lower environments to always and push and pull from the Artifactory Snapshots repository.

By default, mvn-release-plugin removes the SNAPSHOT suffix before rolling out the artifacts (pom/jar) to the repository. I would like to tweak with behavior and actually retain the SNAPSHOT suffix for build artifacts when releasing to Artifactory Snapshots repository. Is this possible without custom scripting ?

Comment: if your goal is to deploy snapshot versions to repository you need to use `maven-deploy-plugin` and `mvn deploy` command.

Comment: That is right but I'd like to be able to use the other features provided by the maven-release-plugin for bumping up the versions, creating git tags etc. The release plugin automatically invokes deploy once all preparation steps are completed.

Comment: would you mind clarifying the desired outcome in your Q? `mvn-release-plugin` perform a plenty of steps and that is bit unclear which of them should be skipped and what should be added.

Comment: Sure, so my end goal is to able to keep snapshots in an Artifactory repo that is dedicated for snapshots only. Artifactory provides that local snapshots repo. The problem is that it expects there to be SNAPSHOT suffix attached to the build artifacts when uploading to the snapshot repo. This is where maven release plugin is not working for me. It removes the SNAPSHOT suffix before deploying artifacts to the repo, which is fine for a release repo but not for the snapshots. 
In short, I would like to keep all the steps in place but modify/skip the step where it is getting rid of the suffix.

Comment: I think that this may be the answer: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-snapshot-release-repository.  Create a "snapshot repository".

Comment: I already have a Snapshot Repository on Artifactory. I can deploy on that repository as well by just using a mvn-deploy command. 
Sadly it does not solve for what I actually need. Instead of doing a mvn-deploy I want to be able to run "mvn release:prepare release:perform" when deploying snapshots to the Artifactory snapshot repo. The issue is that release:prepare phase modifies the pom.xml to bump up the versions (want this to happen) but also gets rid of the SNAPSHOT suffix (don't want this to happen). Without the SNAPSHOT suffix, Artifactory rejects artifacts and returns a 409 status.

Comment: What is the point in using SNAPSHOT and always bumping the version? I mean, the reaso for SNAPSHOTs is that you can build it multiple times WITHOUT changing the version. And tagging a SNAPSHOT makes also little sense because it never goes to production.

Comment: If you have a SNAPSHOT version simply use `mvn deploy` to deploy those artifacts to your repository manager if you want to have a stable version use `mvn release:prepare release:perform` to create that. Maven release plugin generates tags etc. (increments versions numbers) and deploys that state to your repository manager ...assumed that this is correctly configured....

Answer (score 0):

Well, typically release pipeline looks like:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

where:

- `release:prepare` is responsible for bumping project version twice (`snapshot -> release` and `release -> snapshot`), verifying that it is possible to build release version (via [preparationGoals configuration](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals)), committing corresponding changes to SCM and storing information about release version in `release.properties` file
- `release:perform` is responsible for checking out release version from SCM  and deploying release artifacts (via [goals configuration](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals))

Now, our goal is to somehow influence on release pipeline to force it to deploy snapshot artifacts as well and skip(?) deploying release artifacts. The solution actually depends on what snapshot versions we are going to deploy: current or upcoming.

In case of deploying current version, everything should actually be pretty straightforward - just adding `deploy` lifecycle phase before `maven-release-plugin` goals and skipping `release:perform` should work:

```
# skipping release:perform since we do not need to deploy release artifacts
mvn clean deploy release:clean release:prepare
```

however, it doesn't - in my case I'm getting NPE in `AbstractRewritePomsPhase#rewriteParent` method, it looks like goals/steps performed by `deploy` lifecycle phase change maven session state which in turn prevents `release:prepare` goal from running smoothly. I do see two options there:

1. issue two separate `mvn` commands, i.e.:

```
mvn clean deploy 
mvn release:clean release:prepare
```

2. create orchestrating pom file, something like:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tld.orchestrating</groupId>
    <artifactId>orchestrate</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>mvn</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>clean deploy</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>mvn</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>release:clean release:prepare</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and issue something like (however, in that case maven won't prompt you for specifying release and development versions - extra setup is required):

```
mvn exec:exec@deploy exec:exec@prepare -f orchestrate.xml
```

The same applies for deploying upcoming snapshot version - we just need to swap `release:clean release:prepare` and `deploy` goals/phases, i.e. either:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare
mvn clean deploy
```

or

```
mvn exec:exec@prepare exec:exec@deploy -f orchestrate.xml
```